# Email Delivery flow

Tags: php, linux, email, mail-server

Now we have web server and email server

We used email server to broadcast our email blast using EXIM

Our web server using PHP email blast software

Everyday estimate few hundred thousands emails going out from email server.

The bounce emails will be bounced back to our email server but track in web server... will that affect our email delivery?

Our problem is, the email always queue in email server. However, some time when we sent immediately to few emails, we can receive it immediately.

Any solution?

Comment: don't know what the question is. few comments: all mail server queue mail for delivery, time in queue is dependent on a lot of things. Most have a way of checking the queue (exim -bp)

Comment: yeah i know all mail server queue mail for delivery but sometime when i send i can receive it immediately..

Comment: depends where it's sent, send to mail server on same machine, its a very short trip, send across the planet depends on how busy every machine it passes through is. Once it leaves your mail server you have no control or idea when (or IF) it may arrive.

Comment: yeah tats the problem, some client asked me.. y i cant receive it.. and they sent 2.7k emails but 2 people only read...

Comment: theres no way of knowing who read an email, assuming you use the embedded image trick, most clients have remote images off by default.

Comment: exim mail logs will tell you that mail left your server, or not. After that you have no control

Comment: tail -f /var/log/exim/mainlog ??

Comment: and yeah.. our software have include with embedded click.. is will track the person whos open the email...

Comment: well unless there's another question - that's all there is to say.